# Sizing power supply transformer

Tags: power-supply, transformer

I am building a DAC, and right now I am designing the power supply. I would like to have a feedback about the correctness of my calculations before I order a custom made transformer.
I need to power the following things:

1. Tube stage plate voltage: 240V and 40mA circa
2. Tube filaments: 6.3V / 1.5A
3. DAC: 2x3.3v and a total of 400mA
4. PIC microprocessor + LEDs and OLEd display: 3.3V for circa 300mA

For the tube stage power supply I am going to use this design (taken from [this project](http://www.audiodesignguide.com/DAC32/index.html)):
[image]

For the DAC and the PIC I'll use low noise LDOs.

I would like to use a single toroidal transformer with three secondary wirings:

1. Tube plates: 200Vrms / 100mA (200V*1.41 - 2V bridge - 15% main tolerance)
2. Tube Filaments: 9Vrms / 3A (9V*1.41 - 15% main tolerance - 2V bridge - 1.25 regulator )
3. DAC, PIC, LEDs and display: 5Vrms / 1.5A (5V*1.41 - 15% main tolerance - 2V bridge - 0.8 regulator)

Have I estimated right? Is it ok to use a single trafo, or should I use multiple?

Comment: LDOs aren't worth the hassle they cause. use use old-school linears like 7805 - theses are always well behaved.

Comment: I always thought LDO's are an "improved" version of the linear regulators. Am I wrong? I put them in the design because of their very low noise. Which problems could I face from using them? Thanks

Comment: they're more efficient, but often need special treatment to stop them from oscillating.

Comment: A quick practical info for determining the required winding current: After rectification and filtering, rms current drawn from the winding is approximately 2 times the DC current drawn by the load. PS: You don't have to supply the filaments with 6.3VDC. I would supply them directly from a 6V-winding. The winding can also be used for supplying other logic blocks. So a 200V/0.1A and a 6V/5A winding is well enough for your application.